# Scene has disappeared from viewports

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine, scene

I'm such a newbie that I have seemingly pressed the wrong button, and now my scene isn't showing and not rendering either. I think its to do with the camera settings, but I'm at such a loss as to what I've done. Is there a way to reset the cameras? Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your Clip Start is 54 meters, are the objects so far away from the camera that you need such a distant clipping range?

Comment: @AllenSimpson They were all in close range to the camera. I've changed this back to 0.01 m (not sure why it was so high) but I'm still getting the same view

Comment: No chance it has anything to do with those 2 disabled collections in your outliner, is there?